# How to add pure static pages in a cakephp app?

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have a cakephp app which I need to redirect some of its urls to some pure html pages. I can not change these html files as a layout and .ctp file. how can I control the routes of urls like:
mysite.com/en/something
to show some html files in the host?

Comment: Put the file in webroot

Comment: or use `mod_rewrite`

Answer (score 0):

For your route : `mysite.com/en/something`

Open you routes file located at `app/Config/routes.php`

Add this line

```
Router::connect('/en/something', array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'something'));
```

In your Pages controller located at `app/Controller/PagesController.php` Add action to handle this route

```
class PagesController extends AppController{
    public function something(){
        //To disable the layout set it to false
        $this->Layout = false;
    }
}
```

And then, put your html code in the view located at `app/View/Pages/something.ctp`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- your page headers -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- your body content -->
    </body>
</html>
```